# Format gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, formatting

Can anyone give me a website with a tutorial on formatting the asp.net gridview?  I want something that looks really good and professional (not just a basic tutorial that shows how to change colors and fonts in the properties window).

I'm not a great designer, but I'd like something that looks like it was done by a great designer.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help.
http://weblogs.asp.net/kevinbrammer/archive/2008/05/31/asp-net-gridview-themes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- [**GridViewGuy**](http://highoncoding.com/Categories/7_GridView_Control.aspx)

  He has lots of pictures as well as code and explanations. I learned how to create good-looking gridviews from him. Here's a [list of his articles](http://highoncoding.com/Categories/7_GridView_Control.aspx) (scroll down a bit to find ones on colors and highlighting, etc)